# Replace the value of a node in aspx page via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my aspx page having following node.

```
<body onload="return window_onload()" onunload="UnRegisterForAllEvents(varDDSC)">
<form>
Select your favorite Color:
<select id="myList">

  <option>red</option>
  <option>yellow</option>  
  <option>blue</option>
</select>
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="favcolor()" />
</form>

      <object name="SVGEmbed" id="svgembd" type="image/svg+xml" align="left" width="100%" height="100%">          
        <param name="src" id="spara" value="VNETSVGLoader/SVGLoader.aspx?SVGFile=<%=Server.UrlEncode(GetFileUrl)%>&onTagClick=onTagClick&hiliteColour=red&backgroundFill=none&tooltipFontsize=13" />       
      </object>
</body>
```

Now my requirement is i have to select an option(color) from the "mylist" and have to replace the value of param with id "spara" to contain that color 
as following.Suppose i selected yellow from mylist then the param node should appear as follows.

```
<object name="SVGEmbed" id="svgembd" type="image/svg+xml" align="left" width="100%" height="100%">          
            <param name="src" id="spara" value="VNETSVGLoader/SVGLoader.aspx?SVGFile=<%=Server.UrlEncode(GetFileUrl)%>&onTagClick=onTagClick&hiliteColour=yellow&backgroundFill=none&tooltipFontsize=13" />       
          </object>
```

How can i acheive this.Please help :)

Comment: you have to replace the value in the resulted url text, use "hiliteColour=" as the beginning of replacement and look ahead the end on the next "&" character (using regex on attribute value)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#myList").on('change',function(){

    $("#spara").attr('value','VNETSVGLoader/SVGLoader.aspx?SVGFile=<%=Server.UrlEncode(GetFileUrl)%>&onTagClick=onTagClick&hiliteColour='+ $("#myList option:selected").text() +'&backgroundFill=none&tooltipFontsize=13');
});
```

[A JSFiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy7H2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just hook into the change event of the option list:

```
$('#myList').on('change', function (){
    var paramValue = $('#myList option:selected').text();
    $('#spara').attr('value', 'VNETSVGLoader/SVGLoader.aspx?SVGFile=<%=Server.UrlEncode(GetFileUrl)%>&onTagClick=onTagClick&hiliteColour=' + paramValue + '&backgroundFill=none&tooltipFontsize=13paramValue');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all param is a HTML5 element so it can not be nested with in "object" tag so separate your param from object tag.

```
<param name="src" id="spara" value="VNETSVGLoader/SVGLoader.aspx?SVGFile=<%=Server.UrlEncode(GetFileUrl)%>&onTagClick=onTagClick&hiliteColour=yellow&backgroundFill=none&tooltipFontsize=13" />
```

now run this

```
$('#myList').on('change', function (){
    var paramValue = $('#myList option:selected').text();
    $('#spara').attr('value', 'VNETSVGLoader/SVGLoader.aspx?SVGFile=<%=Server.UrlEncode(GetFileUrl)%>&onTagClick=onTagClick&hiliteColour=' + paramValue + '&backgroundFill=none&tooltipFontsize=13paramValue');
}
```

I personally tested and its working.

Comment: Thank you so much chandresh :) But my concern is i cannot move param node outside of object node.if i move param tag outside object tag,my functionality doesnot work.

Comment: Also my page is in HTML 4.0

Comment: Nice. You've managed to copy-paste Pheurton Skeurto's code :)

Comment: @JoakimM I don't write code for free for anybody, helping is another thing :)